# command to sum up webpack configuration in a file?

Tags: webpack

I don't have any webpack.conf.js file but I want to have one from the current configuration. How can I do that ? I assume if I create a new conf file at the root of my project it will erase current configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend quickly going over the documentation.
Link: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
Here is an example from my project.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "local",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: But if i do that, i will erase my current configuration, won't I ? Actually, I just would like to edit the "resolve" section, the rest is ok. i don't understand why the conf file is not mandatory and how to get current conf. Thanks for your help anyway.